# Is it possible to use method attributes to change how this method is run?

Tags: c#, reflection, custom-attributes

I have this method:

```
public object LongRunningTask()
{
    return SomethingThatTakesTooLong();
}
```

I wrote the following code so I can transform a normal method in an async one and still get the `Exception`:

```
public async Task<object> LongRunningTaskAsync()
{
    Exception ex = null;
    object ret = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        object r = null;
        try
        {
            //The actual body of the method
            r = SomethingThatTakesTooLong();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ex = e;
        }
        return r;
    });

    if (ex == null)
        return ret;
    else
        throw ex;
}
```

When I need to do this in several methods, I have to copy all this code and change only the middle.

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
[SomeAttributeThatDoesThatMagically]
public async Task<object> LongRunningTaskAsync()
{
    return SomethingThatTakesTooLong();
}
```

Comment: @TheGeneral But what if that wasn't about async methods, and just an initialization and a finalization? Like: https://pastebin.com/Hp9tpyTU

Comment: Instead of attribute, why don't you write a helper method which should take `Action or Func<T>`. The helper method should run it `asynchronously` using `Task.Run`. So all the invokers classes should call the method using helper method.

Answer (score 1):

Attributes are generally metadata though it is possible to define attributes that can be executed (such as *security behaviours* in WCF) however, something has to be looking for it first.  Your attributes won't just magically run.

I suspect you might have to use a dynamic proxy.

Take a look at how WCF does things for ideas.